# how to run this script for different directories under a single root?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have some sub directories inside `/home/das/work/`

I created a script

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *_K27me3.bed
do
intersectBed -wa -wb -a $i -b /home/das/work/mm9/mm9_prom_genes_2.5kb.bed | awk -v OFS='\t' {'print $1,$2,$3,$7,$8}' > `basename $i`_prom_genes_2.5kb.txt
done
```

It is in the directory `/home/das/work/`

I would like to run it for all the directories in this above mentioned directory.

I was using the below command but it is not able to work. I would like to know 2 different ways to implement the same, either use one script that uses the above script as a function and runs it every time its in the sub directory of the parent or if am invoking the above script separately as below.

command to run the script assuming am in parent directory `/home/das/work`

```
for f in *; do [ -d "$f" ] && cd "$f" && ./annotate_prom.sh;done;cd ..
```

On running the above command am getting the error
`-clustershell: ./annotate_prom.sh: No such file or directory`

Comment: you got the error because the command `cd .. ` is out of `for` cycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap `done` and `cd` and put `..` at the beginning of script path:

for f in *; do [ -d "$f" ] && ( cd "$f" && ../annotate_prom.sh );done

Comment: No if I do the above am getting error `-clustershell: ./annotate_prom.sh: No such file or directory` and then it is taking me to the root directory and it is not staying even in the parent directory where am running it.

Comment: @vchris_ngs : note the `../` . Also I updated the cds.

Comment: ah yes thank you , now it works, I probably should have seen properly the update. I was trying on my own so did notice its entirety. In anycase this works, however if I want to put the above in a function and how shall I do that, rather not calling the script but calling it as a function whenever I go inside different directories of a parent `annotate_prom.sh` should not be a script but a function.

Comment: @vchris_ngs : you still can run function from forked shell. But if you eanted to avoid it: [ -d "$f" ] || continue; if cd "$f" ; then ../annotate_prom.sh ; cd ..; fi